# How to access UI from thread in C++ UWP App?

Tags: visual-c++, uwp, uwp-xaml, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have a native C++ multi-threaded console application.
I ported this application into UWP app with minimal change/
now I want to print out text into textbox in UI as there is no console app available in UWP app.

For this, I required access to a text box from a thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about asynchronous programming in C++.You can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps).It describes the recommended way to consume asynchronous methods in Visual C++ and managing the thread context.You can populate text box within ***task::then*** method.On other hand, you can also use [DispatchedHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher) to access UI,please see this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/use-a-timer-to-submit-a-work-item).

Answer (score 3):

Call Dispatcher->RunAsync on your TextBox (or your page, or any control on the UI thread you want to access, in order to execute your code on the respective UI thread:

```
myTextBox->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
    ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler ([this]
{
    myTextBox->Text = "Test";
}));
```